# What is the best C++ design to contain a class's objects?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, vector

I have a class with many objects that I would like to group in some type of container and also access them with some type of identifier.

```
class Menu {
Object title;
Object play;
Object instructions;
Object pause;
...
};
```

Having each object listed in the class, shown above, is nice because I can access them like, `menu.title`, but then I have to retype every name to add it to a container, `vector.push_back(title)`.

Shown below is how I've always solved the problem. I use an enum's integer value to access the corresponding index. `objects[TITLE]` or `objects[PLAY]`

```
class Menu {
std::vector<Object> objects;
};

enum ObjectTypes {
TITLE, PLAY, INSTRUCTIONS, PAUSE, ...
};
```

I generally dislike this approach because it seems indirect, and when using nested classes and enums, the identifiers can become long and cumbersome. I'm coming from C and somewhat new to C++. Does anybody have a more practical and/or elegant way to solve this problem? C++11 and above welcomed!

Comment: Have you considered a `std::map`? It is an associative container, which means you can reference objects with `menu["title"]` where `"title"` is a `std::string`

Comment: You could make methods that are references in well known locations, or if it is an array, it would be straight-forward to bind them at construction time.

Comment: It could as well be a std::map<YourEnum,Object>.

Comment: I don't want to use a map because then I have the chance to misspell a string, or I still have to have a separate list of strings or container of identifiers, like an enum.

Comment: Why do you want them in a `vector`? Do you have a specific use-case for that?

Comment: @Barry: It doesn't have to be a vector, but there are functions I want to apply to every object

Comment: @acerd If you use a `std::map<ObjectType, Object>` you can't make a spelling mistake. In fact it is safer than a vector, especially with the new strongly typed enums, because you can't accidentally use an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are using is fine.  If you want to avoid cumbersome identifiers, you can make a temporary reference to keep things more succinct.  For example, instead of calling:

```
menu.objects[PAUSE].foo();
menu.objects[PAUSE].bar();
menu.objects[PAUSE].baz();
```

... you could do this when necessary:

```
Object & pause = menu.objects[PAUSE];
pause.foo();
pause.bar();
pause.baz();
```

and it would work the same, but without all of the redundant characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is fine. Using a `std::map<ObjectType, Object>` instead of a `std::vector` might be a little more type-safe.

Either way, if you want to save yourself a little typing you could overload the `operator[]` on `Menu`:

```
Object& operator[](index_type i){ return objects[i]; }
const Object& operator[](index_type i) const { return objects[i]; }
```

[Then you can write](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ty5H7KQAzwtjUljj) `menu[TITLE]`.

Other than that, I don't see how it can be any less cumbersome, there is no redundant information there and, as Jeremy pointed out, if you need an object multiple times you can always create a local reference `auto& title = menu[TITLE];`.

Depending on what other responsibilities `Menu` has maybe you don't need a `Menu` class at all and you can just use a `map` or `vector` directly?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your question depends mostly on your use cases.
I see two main use cases:

1. You want to represent "functions"of a "device" so you can achieve readable code when manipulating that "device" from your code. Such as a MediaPlayer device having play, stop, pause operations. But you dismissed the option to simply add member functions to your "device" object, such as Play(), because you want to re-use your play code also for another device, such as a tuner device. Also, you want to apply operations to all or a sub set of those "functions", for example Enable()/Disable()/ToString()/Trigger(),Configure()...,  which is why the member function approach is not favorable.
2. You want to create a Document Object model, which is more data focused. Such as an Xml Document.

From what you wrote in your question, I assume you have use case 1 in mind. Your `Object` type has all the common operations you need.
Yet, then there are the differences between all those "functions".

In order to stick to your simple approach, you would need to manually set up/configure your Object instances, which might in the long run turn out to be annoying, but hardly avoidable:

```
// Example of "annoying": If you have more than 1 "device", 
// you have to write such a function for each of them.
// Also, there is that fishy bit with Object.Id - the association between
// your configuration data and your object you want to configure.
void ConfigureMenu( std::vector& menuItems, MenuConfigurationData& configData )
{
    for( auto& menuItem : menuItems )
    {
         menuItem.Configure( configData[menuItem.Id] ); // spoiler!
    }
}
```

Also, I am inclined to think that even now you have some code not shown in your question, which configures your objects.

With that in mind, you might want to get rid of the idea to write 1 class type per "device" by hand. The next device/menu will need to be treated the same, yet with dedicated more coding.

So, my advice to you is to get rid of your `class Menu` for good, to abstract your problem and to model your problem rather like: Object is your "function" and a device is simply a set of functions/Objects. Then, your `class Menu` simply becomes an instance, named Menu.

```
typedef uint32_t FunctionId; // for example uint32_t...
typedef std::map<FunctionId,Object> Device; // aka. Menu.
```

Then, in the configuration function you most likely have anyway, you pass in an instance of that `Device` map and your configuration function fills it with Object, properly configured.

```
// those enums are still specific to your concrete device (here Menu) but 
// you can consider the time it takes writing them an investment which will
// pay off later when you write your code, using your functions.
// You assign the function id which is used in your meta-data.
enum class MenuFunctions : FunctionId { play = ..., title = ..., instructions, ... };

// "generic" configuration function.
// Does not only configure your Object, but also puts it inside the device.
void ConfigureDevice( Device& device, ConfigData& configData )
{  // ...
}
```

And later in your code, you can access the functions like this:

```
menu[MenuFunctions::play].Trigger();
```

There are alternative approaches and variations to this, of course. For example, assuming you have your meta data (config data, device descriptions), you could stop coding all that by hand and instead write some code generator which does the job for you.
Your first version of such a generator could create your configuration functions and the enums for you.

With all that in place, the use case of "nested classes" becomes just a matter of creating collections of Device instances. Now, as all your devices are of the same type, you can compose and sub-group them at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

A few different approaches below. I'm not saying which is "best". There are pros/cons to them all.

A) Rather than using a vector (e.g. `class Menu { std::vector<Object> objects; };`), use an array `class Menu {std::array<Object,NObjectTypes> objects;};` when your element count is constant.

B) Just use a class, but provide an api to return a `std::array<>` of references to your objects:

```
class Menu {
 Object title;
 Object play;
 Object instructions;
 Object pause;
...
 std::array<Object*,NObjects> allObjects();
};
```

C) `std::tuple` can be useful when your types are not all the same.

---

For menus, I'll often go with "A".